# In the "Run Query and visualize results" action (from Azure Monitor Logs connector), anyway to manipulate the results from the output?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-monitoring

I'm creating my first logic app, and I was wondering if there was a way of utilizing the output of the "Run query and visualize results" action (from [Azure Monitor Logs connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuremonitorlogs/)) to get the **row results** from the query. Similarly to how the "Run query and **list** results" action works (is also part of the Azure Monitor Logs connector), I want to get an array that holds the rows returned from the query and use it in my conditional logic right after the my query action.

The reason I'm using the "Run query and visualize results" action as opposed to the latter, is because I like the HTML table (`Attachment Content`) it creates for later consumption. I could easily just run the "Run query and list results" action to get the array of rows I need for my condition action but I don't want to query for the same information twice.

Is there a way to get the query results as an array from the `Body` or `Attachment Content` [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuremonitorlogs/#visualizeresults) from the "Run Query and visualize results" action so I can perform my check of whether any records were returned or not?

[image: My logic app flow]

Answer (score 0):

I am checking the body content by converting them to base64.

```
"expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@{base64ToString(body('Run_query_and_visualize_results')?['attachmentContent'])}",
                                    "<body>The query yielded no dataTable.</body>"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```